# Third party service to trigger web service

Tags: asp.net, windows, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for a third-party service or tool that can trigger or hit a web page at scheduled times. Does anyone know of any? I currently use my windows scheduler to hit these pages, but there are gaps in this since I don't run my computer 24 / 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of free website monitoring services out there that check your site's availability by testing whether a given URL responds properly.  One that I use is http://mon.itor.us/  Give it the URL of your page and that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

One other alternative is [Pingdom.](http://www.pingdom.com/) They offer a free account for monitoring one web site. You can set Pingdom to send email or SMS if your site goes down and you can configure the service to hit your page for example once in every 5 minutes. You can set the check resolution quite freely.

Some other alternatives are [MonitorUs](http://mon.itor.us/) (which RichieHindle already mentioned), [SiteUptime](http://www.siteuptime.com/) and [HyperSpin](http://www.hyperspin.com/en/).

Answer (score 0):

I created an open source app called Pinger. You can do unlimited URLs with intervals of your choosing. The docs has instructions for getting running on Heroku quickly:

https://github.com/austinthecoder/pinger

Only problem is, currently, you can only set an interval, not a specific time.